# Troubleshooting export with heredoc

Tags: export, heredoc, lsf

**INTRODUCTION:**

I have been using this construct to set the current group after opening a terminal at a compute server:

```
newgrp project1_group << ANYCODE
  cd ~/WORK/project1_rundir
  bsub xterm &
ANYCODE
```

After executing this script, new terminal is opened at a compute server, in the specified project rundir, and the primary group is set correctly. 
It works just fine...

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

Now I would like to set an environment variable at a compute server using the same construct:

```
export POLICYFILE=~/WORK/project1_rundir/.policyfile << ANYCODE
  cd ~/WORK/project1_rundir
  bsub xterm &
ANYCODE
```

It doesn't do anything, not even a terminal is opened.

**Does anyone have an explanation, why does `newgrp` work and `export` not?**

**Is there a way to make this work (not necessarily using the heredoc)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved (even better, without heredoc)...

The final solution is implemented as follows:

```
cd ~/WORK/project1_rundir
bsub -I -env "all, POLICYFILE=~/WORK/project1_rundir/.policyfile" xterm &
```